# Where is the Kestrel server log?

Tags: kestrel-http-server

Where is the Kestrel server log?
Im trying to find the cause of why my kestrel server every a few days get down.

So i think to find some clue in the kestrel log (if it has one). Something like the iis log configured in the web.config.

Answer (score 0):

By default the logger does not saves the logs into a file. 
I recommend to use [Serilog](https://serilog.net/). Easy to configure and can save the logs into a file.

Other options and doc can be found on [github](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file).

Answer (score 0):

Check `/var/log/syslog`. There are many services that log to it.

There are utilities for accessing it, instead of accessing it directly. One is `journalctl`. The messages from a service can be listed using (substituting the service name):

```
sudo journalctl -fu kestrel-helloapp.service
```

See [Host ASP.NET Core on Linux with Nginx | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=linux-ubuntu#view-logs).